# Grid interval settings crash before changing values in print composer of QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

I am using QGIS 2.4 in Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite. Just trying to produce a map with cartographic symbology in the print composer. Map data: polygon and line shapefiles projected in SAD69 / UTM zone 23S/ EPSG:29193, drawing scale 1:124,051. First, I add a new map on canvas and change map scale; thereafter, I try to create a grid from item properties, in the following order: I select the Show grid checkbox; then, I select cross option as the grid type; next, I change both X and Y interval to, say, 10.0000000. Here is the point: after changing Y interval, Mac OS spinning beach ball of death appears and QGIS stops responding.

What am I doing wrong or skipping steps in the construction of the grid?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem occured because you using unmatched interval (from screenshot that you post, i dont see interval units, whether its on mapunits,milimeter, or centimetre)

[image]

Or if in your machine the interval units was not showed up, then make sure your layer are using crs with distance unit (like meter or feet). Just look at layer properties and go to metadata tab and see the used crs
(usually crs without distance unit (degree) show

> +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

if this is the case then you have to resave your layer(data) and change CRS of your new data with CRS that has distance unit like meters
[image]

and again try to use the print composer again